# Javascript unexpected outcome

Tags: javascript

I am doing an excercise that challenges me a bit, and I just thought that might be a good idea to ask for some help here. I know it might be very easy question for the majority of you, but as I am new to coding hope this won't botter you too much.

Below is my code associated with the excercise. The code shouldn't run in my opinion as the **var weapon** is not specified. The problem is that the code runs and the console visualises some outcome.

I would assume there is something wrong with my conditional statements, but might be wrong..

```js
var room = 'gallery';
var suspect = 'Ms. Van Cleve';
var weapon = '';
var solved = false;

if (room === 'billiards room') {
  weapon = 'pool stick';
  if (suspect === 'Mr. Parkes')
    solved = true;
} else if (room === 'gallery') {
  weapon = 'trophy';
  if (suspect === 'Ms. Van Cleve')
    solved = true;
}

if (solved) {
  console.log(suspect + ' did it in the ' + room + ' with the ' + weapon + '!');
}

//Outcome is "Ms. Van Cleve did it in the gallery with the trophy!"
```

Comment: "var weapon is not defined" vs `var weapon = '';` on the 3rd line. Please be consistent

Comment: `var weapon`  is defined.

Comment: i don't see any problem here and i can run your code and achieve what you expect @@

Comment: I don't see any problem here and weapon is defined too but empty

Comment: And even if you don't declare weapon ur code will work because of js variable hoisting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code result does not depend on `weapon`. Have a look at what you have defined

```js
var room = 'gallery';
var suspect = 'Ms. Van Cleve';
var weapon = '';
var solved = false;
```

and the `else if` part of your code

```js
} else if (room === 'gallery') { // TRUE
  weapon = 'trophy';
  if (suspect === 'Ms. Van Cleve') // TRUE
    solved = true; // so now solved is true
}
```

As `solved` is true you get console output because

```js
if (solved) {
  console.log(suspect + ' did it in the ' + room + ' with the ' + weapon + '!');
}
```